# which among these is good according to url optimization for search engine - google?

Tags: google, search-engines, seo

which among these is good according to url optimization for search engine - google?

Keyword -
**hot jobs in paris**

paris.hotjobsin.com

hotjobsin.com/hotjobs/paris

hotjobsin.com/paris/hot-jobs-in-paris.html

hotjobsin.com/hot-jobs-in-paris.com

paris.hotjobsin.com/hot-jobs-in-paris.com

**Any thoughts.**

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to go much farther than 2 subdirectories.

Eg: hotjobsin.com/europe/paris/hot-jobs-in-paris-france

Comment: I don't see any subdomains there.

Comment: I mean't sub directories.